# ReadFile from a subprocess keeps returning same data

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, process, pipe

I am trying to create a subprocess and communicate with it asynchronously using windows pipes and then re-direct its output to cout of the master process as the output is being generated by the child.
Here is my code now:

```
HANDLE hWriteOUT, hReadOUT, hWriteIN, hReadIN;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saPipe = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = { 0 };
STARTUPINFO procSi;
DWORD dwWritten, dwRead;
int bufsize = 6000;
char buf[6000];
saPipe.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
saPipe.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
saPipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
CreatePipe(&hReadOUT, &hWriteOUT, &saPipe, 0);
SetHandleInformation(hReadOUT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
CreatePipe(&hReadIN, &hWriteIN, &saPipe, 0);
SetHandleInformation(hWriteIN, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

ZeroMemory(&procSi, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
procSi.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
procSi.hStdError = hWriteOUT;
procSi.hStdOutput = hWriteOUT;
procSi.hStdInput = hReadIN;
procSi.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(
        NULL,
        (LPSTR) "app.exe",
        NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &procSi, &procInfo);

WriteFile(hWriteIN, "go movetime 1000\n", strlen("go movetime 1000\n"),
        &dwWritten, NULL);

auto start = clock();
auto seconds = 1.5;;
do {
    Sleep(500);
    cout << "cycle..." << endl;
    buf[0]=char(NULL);
    ReadFile(hReadOUT, buf, bufsize, &dwRead, NULL);
    cout << buf;
    //loop for 1.5 seconds = 3 cycles
} while ((double(clock() - start) / ((double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) < seconds);
```

The problem is that consecutive reads do not seem to access information sequentially. If i simplify the output, then instead of something like:

cycle...
   1
   2
   3
   cycle...
   4
   5
   6
   cycle...
   7
   8
   done!

I am seeing something like:

cycle...
   1
   2
   3
   cycle...
   4
   2
   3
   cycle...
   8
   done!
   4

Some parts of the output are missing and some are being skipped-over!
If i get rid of the for loop and just do one read after a longer delay I do get the expected result.

I am assuming that the fact that my subprocess keeps dumping stuff into the pipe invalidates the offset which ReadFile is supposed to keep.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadFile reads bytes up to the `bufsize` parameter you pass in. It does not put a zero byte at the end, so you can't just treat the buffer as a null terminated string.

It returns the number of bytes read i the 4th parameter (`dwRead` in your case). However, you are not using the value that the function is setting into that variable.

This means that when you print out your buffer the second time around the loop, if the `ReadFile` call only reads one byte, the `cout` statement will still print the values that are in the buffer from the previous call. Which is why you get "4 2 3" as the readfile has just replaced the 1 with a 4.

One way to fix this is to leave some space at the end of the buffer for a NULL byte and then to set a NULL byte into the buffer so that `cout` knows when to stop. (Note: setting the first byte to NULL doesn't work as that is the first thing that ReadFile will write to).

Something like:

```
ReadFile(hReadOUT, buf, bufsize - 1, &dwRead, NULL);
buf[dwRead] = '\0';
cout << buf;
```

Note the `- 1` after bufsize, otherwise you might get unlucky and read 6000 bytes and try to set the 6001 byte of your array to `\0` which would be a buffer overrun.

You could also put in some sanity checking to make sure that `dwRead` is negative and is less than bufsize.

There are other ways to fix this (append the exact number of bytes you retrieved into a string and then print it out at the end. Or you could completely zero out your buffer before the `ReadFile` call, but that would be overkill).

I am not sure why you would be missing the 5, 6, and 7, due to this problem, but it may be related.